# OpenCV integration With Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, opencv

I am having a problem integrating my openCV with QT. What I have done is installed openCV and Qt for Mac OSX (openCV version 3.1.0) and have went to the myproject.pro file and have added

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-05-15T23:16:25
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = cam
TEMPLATE = app




// new
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = RP_openCV_01
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib \
-lopencv_highgui.3.1.0 \
-lopencv_core.3.1.0

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I have tried to add the header files to the main .cpp and have errors stating files not found, can someone please explain to em the appropriate set-up?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow [this](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/11/using-opencv-3-qt-creator-3-2-qt-5-3/) for installing and using OpenCV with Qt.

Make sure that you compile your OpenCV without the `WITH_QT=ON` flag. Will be better even to set it to `WITH_QT=OFF` just to make sure, even though it suppose to be the default.